# Unity3D Facebook APK not working on Scene change

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine

When I start the game and click Login with Facebook, I am able to successfully log into my account, my profile picture is set, along with my name.
However, when I hit play and the next scene is loaded, my profile picture is not updating, nor is my name. It's as if I'm not signed into facebook in scene two.
Both my FBprofile and Name object in scene two are referenced correctly.
So, my question is how can I alter my code in-order for it to automatically detect that I am infact logged into facebook when Scene 2 opens.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class FacebookScript : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public GameObject facebookButton;
    public GameObject facebookUsername;
    public GameObject facebookAvitar;
    public GameObject facebookFrame;

    void Awake()
    {
        FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);
        DealWtihFBMenus (FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }
    void SetInit()
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Logged in");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log ("FB not logged in.");
        }
        DealWtihFBMenus (FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }   
    void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) 
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }   
    public void FBlogin()
    {
        List<string> permissions = new List<string> ();
        permissions.Add ("public_profile");

        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(permissions, AuthCallback);
    }
    void AuthCallback(IResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null) 
        {
            Debug.Log (result.Error);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Debug.Log ("FB Not logged in(AuthCallback)");
        }
        DealWtihFBMenus (FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }
    void DealWtihFBMenus(bool isLoggedIn)
    {
        if (isLoggedIn) 
        {
            facebookButton.SetActive (false);

            FB.API ("/me?fields=first_name", HttpMethod.GET, DisplayUsername);
            FB.API ("/me/picture?type=square&height=128&width=128", HttpMethod.GET, DisplayProfilePic);
        }
        else
        {
            facebookButton.SetActive (true);
        }
    }
    void DisplayUsername(IResult result)
    {
        facebookUsername.SetActive (true);
        Text UserName = facebookUsername.GetComponent<Text> ();
        if (result.Error == null) 
        {
            UserName.text = "" + result.ResultDictionary ["first_name"];

        }
    }    
    void DisplayProfilePic(IGraphResult result)
    {
        if (result.Texture != null) 
        {
            facebookAvitar.SetActive (true);
            facebookFrame.SetActive (true);
            Image ProfilePic = facebookAvitar.GetComponent<Image> ();
            ProfilePic.sprite = Sprite.Create (result.Texture, new Rect (0, 0, 128, 128), new Vector2 ());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: @SotirisTsartsaris DontDestroyOnLoad won't work because I can't update the references upon Scene change.